# R: Why an xts object becomes a zoo object after calling transform()?

Tags: r, transform, xts

transform() removes the class "xts" qualifier from my xts object:

```
> class(myxts)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> myxts = transform(myxts, ABC = 1)
> class(myxts)
[1] "zoo"
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no xts method for `transform`, so the zoo method is dispatched.  The zoo method explicitly creates a new zoo object.

```
> zoo:::transform.zoo
function (`_data`, ...) 
{
    if (is.null(dim(coredata(`_data`)))) 
        warning("transform() is only useful for matrix-based zoo series")
    zoo(transform.data.frame(data.frame(coredata(`_data`)), ...), 
        index(`_data`), attr(`_data`, "frequency"))
}
<environment: namespace:zoo>
```

You could simply wrap your `transform` calls in `as.xts`, or your example could be written as `myxts$ABC <- 1`.

Comment: I've tried myxts = as.xts(transform(myxts, ...)) but I get this error when I try to access myxts by a date index: "Error in function (year = 1970, month = 1, day = 1, hour = 0, min = 0,  : 
  unused argument(s) (tz1 = "", tz2 = "EST", tz3 = "EDT")"

Comment: @RobertKubrick: it's nearly impossible for me to guess what's causing that error. A reproducible example would really help.

Comment: I'm going to post this as a separate question.